# HighChart Heatmap with JSON data

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to integrate JSON specific data into a heatmap offered by highmaps/highcharts.

The example on

[Link to HeatMap Demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas)

shows how to use CSV approach to load the data. But I was not able to get it running with a JSON array. Can anyone provide an equivalent to the CSV from the example to get the same heatmap chart, or show me the way to another example based on JSON?

Thx in advance.

Cheers Peter

Comment: What does your json look like? The heatmap uses x/y coordinate matrix `[x, y, value]`.

Comment: tried it with that one: 
[
        ["2013-04-01",0,-0.7],
        ["2013-04-02",0,-3.4],
        ["2013-04-03",0,-1.1]
    ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert that to the col/row point instead of date string. You are going to have 2 category axis: x and y. Then the index of x/y axis becomes the [x, y, value]. So, if your data starts on "2013-04-01" then it is your first index such that `[ ["2013-04-01",0,-0.7], ["2013-04-02",0,-3.4], ["2013-04-03",0,-1.1] ]` becomes:

```
[ [0,0,-0.7], [1,0,-3.4], [2,0,-1.1] ]
```

Note that this is just one row's worth of data. What is your `y` component?

EDIT:
If your yAxis component will be the hour of the day then you would set up your axii like so:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['2013-04-01', '2013-04-02', '2013-04-03'],
    labels: {
        rotation: 90
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    categories: ['Midnight', '1 am', '2 am', '3 am', '4 am', '5 am', '6 am', '7 am', '8 am', '9 am', '10 am', '11 am', 'Noon', '1 pm', '2 pm', '3 pm', '4 pm', '5 pm', '6 pm', '7 pm', '8 pm', '9 pm', '10 pm', '11 pm'],
    min: 0,
    max: 23,
    reversed: true
},
```

Then you series would look something like:

```
series: [{
    borderWidth: 0,
    nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
    data: [ [0,0,-0.7], [1,0,-3.4], [2,0,-1.1] ]
}]
```

Live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/E3VGR/).

There are other items I added there that I will let you figure out (why do I set `reversed: true`, what is the colorAxis, etc). The important thing to note is that the `series.data` format is different from any other highchart setup.

Comment: well the second part of the inner array is the hour of day. That would be the y component

But if I have a look at the heatmap example based on the CSV file. How can it be done like this:
Date,Time,Temperature
2013-01-01,0,1.3
2013-01-01,1,1.4

Comment: Okay, so you have some range of times for each day. That is really easy. Your array becomes `[ [dayIndex, hourIndex, value]...]`.

Comment: ok, but then... how can I set x and y axis definition? 
with CSV parsing it seems that the Date is automatically parsed into a Date Object.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/

Comment: You need to set your `xAxis.categories` to the days and your `yAxis.categories` to the hours. Let me wire up an example.

Comment: Thx in advance. I will give it a try. Based on the data I get back from the backend application I should be able to create javascript objects for the categories and the data for the series. Could be quite a number cause I want to show up to a few thousand values there but lets see :-)

Comment: Depending on your datastore it could be easy or hard. We get our data back as xvalue, yvalue, datavalue and we then loop through this item to pull out our x and y categories and assign the index to a new series.data object. Many ways to solve this issue. For some items we actually query to get 3 data sets: x categories, y categories, and data. it all really depends on your needs.